# Fetching Images from server using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, datetime, socket.io

I am creating an **app** where i have a rectagular div on screen. I have 100 images on **server** and i want to display each image for **2 min** inside the div and then next image after 2 min and so on.  I want to do this using **Node.js and Socket.io.**

Moreover, I want **time** on all **clients** connected to my sever should be same like an **online examination**. How to do this using **Node.js** ? I just want an idea. And if possible give the related links or code too.

Comment: http://yoramkornatzky.com/2013/07/20/real-time-auctions-with-node-js/comment-page-1/#comment-55   I got this useful link.. But help is welcomed..

Comment: Even if you want to use Socket.io for the coordination with the server, you'll still want to load the images via HTTP(S) like normal.

Comment: @Bryan Should i do it on client side using ajax &jquery(so that only after particular interval each will load) ?? What do you suggest? Because loading 100 images will take too much time.. Do you have any other Idea?

Comment: @abishek Yes, you'd certainly want to do it dynamically somehow (pure JS on the client or AJAX, depending on where your logic is) so you don't load all of the images right away.

Comment: @brayn i successfully did that. Now i can load 100-150 images comfortably. Do you have idea how to maintain common timer on all client like an online examination?

Comment: @abishek That's when the socket.io part would come in to play, to somehow synchronize those timers. But the implementation of that? No, I don't have any solid ideas.